# How to jump inside a Listview (changing it's visible items)

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a listview that has a Jump function i coded, i wanted the End User to just write the Index in a textbox and click a button and it auto selects the indexed item, and put focus into it, makes the item the Listview "Topitem", this is the button code:

```
if (toolStripTextBox2.Text != "")
        {
            listView1.Items[Convert.ToInt32(toolStripTextBox2.Text)].Selected = true;
            //listView1.TopItem.Index = Convert.ToInt32(toolStripTextBox2.Text);
        }
```

I cannot change the Topitem, is there anyway to change the topitem, as in change view position, not change value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `EnsureVisible` method found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ensurevisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Although this will only scroll the specified item into view, and won't necessarily scroll the item to be the "TopItem" in the list view.

The Remarks section at the above link shows that it may be possible to force an item to the top of the viewable area by calling `EnsureVisible` twice - the first to ensure it is visible, and the second to force the list view to scroll it to the top.

Comment: if it's visible then it's a win, sir, Thank you.
EDIT: calling it twice doesn't work, as long as it is whithin a viewable area, the command dies.

Comment: I just found another possibility - set the TopItem property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.topitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Sadly that only gets and sets it's values, it doesn't change it as an item in a list.